# Using Breeze in IntelliJ

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

I downloaded breeze jar files from the [link](https://jar-download.com/?search_box=breeze_2.10-0.11.2), then I went to Project Structure->Modules->Dependencies and added downloaded jar files.

I made a new project->Scala class and wrote the following code:

```
import breeze.linalg_
object Scrpting extends App{
  println("hello")
}
```

I get the following error.

```
Error:(4, 8) not found: object breeze
import breeze.linalg_
```

I tried to search online, but was unable to find any clear useful resource on how to use breeze with IntelliJ. Can someone please help me with this? I am using Mac OS.

Comment: Temporarily comment out the import statement, then print out the classpath and see if your Breeze JAR is in it: `val cp = System.getProperty("java.class.path"); val sep = System.getProperty("path.separator"); cp.split(sep).foreach(println)`

Comment: I get a dialogue box saying that this is Java code, and if I would like to convert it to Scala. After converting I get: `val cp = System.getProperty("java.class.path")
  val sep = System.getProperty("path.separator")
  cp.split(sep).foreach(println)`. I have 0 errors

Comment: You can choose to "convert to Scala" or not; I don't think it matters. It's Scala code, but I used semicolons because comments are displayed on a single line on this site, and I wanted to give you correct code.

Comment: Process finished with exit code 0.

Comment: Yes, but what did it print to the console?

Comment: [I cannot access chat from this location.] The error you are getting means that the class you are trying to access is not in the classpath. I see that you have added many Breeze JARs to your classpath - but perhaps not the one that contains the class you are trying to access. Try to find out which Breeze JAR contains that class and make sure it's in your classpath.

Comment: Oh ok, do I need to change something in build.sbt?

Comment: Check out "libraryDependencies" at https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `build.sbt` file, make sure you add all the dependencies listed under "libraryDependencies" at

https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze

Comment: Yes I added those lines, it did not work. If I download all files then there are no jars and I don't know how to add them, and there is no clear way mentioned on the link you provided.

Comment: If your `build.sbt` contains those lines, then re-open the project in IntelliJ as File -> Open -> /some/dir/build.sbt -> Open as a project (not as a file). IntelliJ will build a list of dependencies based on the settings in `build.sbt`, and that should include the JAR you need for that import statement.

Comment: See for instance https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Getting+Started+with+SBT